# Sony Cyber-shot DSC RX100 - photo without memory card

Tags: sony

Using a Sony Cyber-shot DSC RX100 , I went out to photograph but later realized the SD card was not in the camera.

I am assuming that there must be some internal memory where the photos are stored, but I cant seem to figure out how to access it to retrieve the photos .

Is there a way to retrieve the photos?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to recover photos taken without a memory card?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/64856/is-there-any-way-to-recover-photos-taken-without-a-memory-card)

Comment: Related; [How can I retrieve internal memory photos on D3100?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/35363/15871) and [Retrieving photos taken without a memory card](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/65577/15871) and [Why would you want to take pictures without a memory card in your camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/18948/15871) and [Where are my photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/69336/15871)

Comment: The problem with that possible duplicate suggestion is that the other question is about an older point and shoot model which _did_ have a small amount of internal persistent storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, cameras today have only temporary internal memory, not persistent storage. That is meant to hold photos as they are being processed and written to your memory card, and cannot be used as a replacement for one.

I'm afraid your photos are lost — they were never recorded.

Most cameras flash a warning when no card is in use, and have a setting where no photos can be taken in that case. (I imagine the only reason to allow otherwise is to demo the camera on shop floors.)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you assume that there must be some internal memory where the photos are stored? There is not. That is the whole point of the memory card. Unfortunately, your photos were not stored anywhere. There is nothing to retrieve.